# JS: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'createElement'

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, createelement

Im trying to let a js script create some tags with an for loop, but i get the error Object # has no method 'createElement'

Its the following function:

```
function tabListRefresh() {
  // Get Container
  var container = document.getElementById("tabListContainer");

  // Clear container
  container.innerHTML = "";

  // Create tags
  for( var k=0; k<tabs.length; k++ ) {

    // Create div tag
    var div = container.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class", "tab");          

    // Include title into tag
    div.innerHTML = tabs[k][0] + " ";

    // Create closetab-icon
    var closebtn = div.createElement("button");    
    div.setAttribute("type", "button");        
    div.setAttribute("class", "closetab");    
    closebtn.innerHTML = "&times;";

 }


  /* XML Structure:
      <div class="tab">
        Dashboard
        <button type="button" class="closetab">&times;</button>
      </div>
                                                                    */
}
```

Comment: The error is crystal clear. `div` elements don't have  a `createElement` method.

Comment: If you were hoping to one-line it: `var div = container.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));`

Answer (score 3):

**Container has no creatElement method**

Document has it

```
var elem= document.createElement("div");

container.appendChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
document.createElement("div");
```